# Security Exception attempting to deploy a solution

Tags: central-administration, farm-solution

I must have upset SharePoint somehow as I can't use the Central Administration to deploy an installed solution.  Everything I do returns the wonderful '[SecurityException: Access denied.]' error.

I'm a domain administrator and a member of the local Administrators group.  In fact, I went thru every local group on this machine and added my user account.  Still no luck.

I AM able to deploy the solution via the SharePoint Management Shell though.

Any idea on how to fix the CA?

Answer (score 5):

When you launch your browser, you need to Run as Administrator.

Comment: All this time and pain and it was as simple as 'running the browser as an Administrator'.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Creating a new web application and Managing Services are other Central Admin actions that require your running as Admin. Sometimes buttons will be greyed out. The best bet is to always run Central Admin as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a solution you must make sure you are a Farm Administrator. This won't be set through AD. So go to Central Administration and ensure your user account is added as a Farm Administrator. You may need to use a Farm Administrator account (the one that was setup) to add your user as such.

Comment: According to 'Central Administration:
Site Settings : People and Groups - Farm Administrators' there are 2 farm administrators: BUILTIN\Administrators and my account.  That's probably why I can use the shell.